# How to make a checkbox do a continuous task, until it gets unchecked?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

Anyone have any idea how to make check box do a task until it gets unchecked?

```
JCheckBox chckbxInspecAuto = new JCheckBox("Inspe. Auto.");
chckbxInspecAuto.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
try {

      gimage = vision.grab();
      cvSaveImage("image001.bmp", gimage);
      ipanel.loadImage("image001.bmp");


            } catch (com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


        }
    });
```

EDIT: The code is over there now...

Comment: Can you pls elaborate the task ??

Comment: when it gets checked start a thread that does your taks but also checks from time to time if the checkbox has been disabled so that it knows when to stop.

Comment: It will take pictures when the checkbox is enabled, with a inteval of 1 second, right now it take pictures only one time.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class or even Thread to implement the functionality you want the checkbox to control. Create methods `contiueWorking()` and `stopWorking()` and in the run method check some boolean flag to see whether to do the task or sleep. 
As Robin commented on a post below, swing components should only be accessed from the Event Worker Thread. I violated this rule in my example below because I wanted to produce something simple and since the running thread spends most of its time sleeping, it works fine.

I would use SwingWorker for a more time consuming task that I wish to update the user on as it executes. For instance, say we have a thread generate and then send a set of email messages, and for each e-mail, display some text in the UI that confirms the message was sent or indicates why it was undeliverable. Each message may lock the Thread up for a while. The UI will not be updated in sync with the Thread's execution of the e-mail task. SwingWorker to the rescue.  The java2s.com site has a [SwingWokerDemo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/SwingWorkerfromJDK6SE.htm).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *  The sequence of prime integers is calculated and displayed on the screen.
 *  This little program demonstrates how a checkbox can be used
 *  to start and stop a thread. 
 */
public class ThreadDemo extends JFrame {

    JCheckBox runningCB;
    JTextArea displayArea;
    JTextField delayField;
    PrimeCalcThread workerThread = null;
    public ThreadDemo() {
        super("Prime Numbers");
        runningCB = new JCheckBox("Calculate Primes");
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(runningCB);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Dealy: "));
        delayField = new JTextField(10);
        delayField.setText("500");
        topPanel.add(delayField);
        getContentPane().add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        displayArea = new JTextArea(30,80);
        displayArea.setText("2, 3, 5, ");
        displayArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(displayArea);
        getContentPane().add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();

        runningCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(runningCB.isSelected() ) {
                    if(workerThread != null)
                        workerThread.contiueWorking();
                    else {
                        workerThread = new PrimeCalcThread();
                        workerThread.start();
                    }
                }
                else {
                   if(workerThread != null)
                       workerThread.stopWorking(); 
                }
            }
        });
        delayField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String input = delayField.getText().trim();
                try {
                    int d = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    workerThread.setDelay(d);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { }
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        ThreadDemo window = new ThreadDemo();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * When this thread is active it calculates prime numbers. The Thread 
     * continues until it is paused with stopWorking() or until the 
     * boolean field endThread is set to true.
     */
    class PrimeCalcThread extends Thread {
        ArrayList<Integer> primeList;
        int delay = 500;
        boolean active = true;
        boolean endThread = false;
        private int lastPrime;

        public PrimeCalcThread() {
            primeList = new ArrayList<> (1024);
            primeList.add(2); primeList.add(3); primeList.add(5);
            lastPrime=5;
        }

        public void run() {
            while(!endThread) {
                if(active) {
                    calcNextPrime();
                    displayArea.append(lastPrime + ", ");
                }
                try { sleep(delay);  }
                catch(InterruptedException whatever) { }
            }
        }

        private void calcNextPrime() {
            int p = lastPrime+2;
            while(!isPrime(p))
                p+=2;
            primeList.add(p);
            lastPrime = p;
        }

        /**
         * Checks if p is prime by checking for divisibility by all primes in the
         * calculated primeList so far. This method only works if sqrt(p) < lastPrime
         */
        private boolean isPrime(int p) {
            int maxCheck = (int) Math.sqrt(p) + 1;
            for(int prime: primeList) {
                if(p % prime == 0)
                    return false;
                if(prime > maxCheck)
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int getLastPrime() {
            return lastPrime;
        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> getPrimeList() {
            return primeList;
        }

        public int getDelay() {
            return delay;
        }

        public void setDelay(int waitTime) {
            if(waitTime>=0)
                delay = waitTime;
        }

        public void contiueWorking() {
            active=true;
        }
        public void stopWorking() {
            active=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me the WorkerThread class? Never used Threads before, sorry

Comment: I gave you a more complete example now and a reference for SwingWorker. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** Well create a Daemon Thread and run it in an infinite loop, let it keep checking whether the JCheckBox is checked or not using  `isSelected()` method or `ItemListener`.

**-** And when the `JCheckBox` **gets selected** then **create a Thread** to execute the task, **or** use `SwingWorker Class` which properly synchronizes the UI and Non-UI thread's work.

Comment: Swing components should only be accessed from the EDT. Please clarify that in your first point

Comment: The part of the code that i need to be running with a inteval when the checkbox is activated is over there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task.

If a task is on other process on other machine you could simply send the right messages.
If the task is a separated thread in the same application you could do what wxyz suggests or you could use some kind of Listener with the ability of start and stop the Thread (the thread is always the same or you are creating a new one every time you select the checkbox?).

My favorite one would be to use Observer pattern in the "PUSH" way, so you would use some kind of external signal to the thread which when sent would create and/or stop it.